# Ruby: %q with strings [case]

Tags: ruby, string

I encountered this line:

```
at = @seq.slice(@seq.length - 2, 2).count(%q[at])
```

where `@seq` is a string. I know how `slice` and `%q` work, but I don't get the idea of putting a variable `at` (which we define here) as an argument of `[]` after `%q`.

Comment: You are not getting anything. `%q` or `[]` does not work in isolation. `%q[]` is  a single literal notation for string. Also, `at` within `%q[]` is not a variable. `%q[at]` is just a verbose way of writing `"at"`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a very verbose code.

- `@seq.length - 2` gives the index of the second to last character in `@seq`.
- `@seq.slice(@seq.length - 2, 2)` gives the last two characters in `@seq`.
- Applying `count(%q[at])` to it returns the number of occurrences of characters in `%q[at]` (i.e., `"at"`) in it, which counts `"a"` and `"t"`. Since there are only two characters, it would be either `0`, `1`, or `2`.

Comment: OK, so it counts both "a" and "t" ? Thats good to know, from your previous explanations I thought it counts "at"

Comment: @maciek My previous explanation was wrong. I changed it.

Comment: Perhaps something like 

@seq[-2..-1].count('at')

it is more readable?

Comment: Strictly speaking `%q[at]` is equivalent to `'at'`, not `"at"`. M

Answer (score 2):

`%q` with paired delimiters are similar to the single quoted strings. In other words, `%q[at]`, or `%q!at!`, or `%q{at}`, are all equivalent to `'at'`.

```
%q[at]
# => "at"
```

P.S, `%Q` works similarly, but like double quoted strings.